# Drop shadow for text in TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have `TextBox` with `TextBox.BackColor = Transparent;`

I need to do for example but in WinForms [how to add dropshadoweffect to just the text of a textbox (programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257063/how-to-add-dropshadoweffect-to-just-the-text-of-a-textbox-programmatically)

Comment: I don't have for WinForms.

Comment: @mzk not easy for `winforms`, not clear what you want but `BackColor = Color.Transparent` is not supported by `TextBox` in `winforms`, even `Shadowed text` is hard to achieve.

Comment: I came to Codeproject.com is an example.

Comment: @mzk looks like you have found some example on `CodeProject`?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4390/AlphaBlendTextBox-A-transparent-translucent-textbo

Comment: Most easy way will be to create a user control(textbox) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the background color 'Transparent' in textbox directly.
Please refer the enclosed the URL to accomplish your task :
[Transparency for windows forms textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050249/c-sharp-transparency-on-textbox)

Comment: Can help on this topic shadow text into TextBox